# Why this fragment of code doesnt work but the others do?

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error, runtimeexception

This dont work: [Only changed the .map()]

```
return findTechnician.findWithUser()
                          .stream()
                          .map(this::toDTO)
                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

`Error:`
`Method threw 'java.lang.TypeNotPresentException' exception.`

`Type com.grupoaev.aevgestion.domain.entities.solicitudes.Tecnico not present`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujhQu.png)

This is my actual class:

```
private static class TechniciansModel extends LoadableDetachableModel<Collection<TechnicianDatesDTO>> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @SpringBean
        private FindTechnician findTechnician;
        @SpringBean
        private FindTechnicalUserAbsences findTechnicalUserAbsences;

        public TechniciansModel() {
            Injector.get().inject(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected Collection<TechnicianDatesDTO> load() {

            return findTechnician.findWithUser()
                          .stream()
                          .map(t->toDTO(t))
                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }

        @NotNull
        private TechnicianDatesDTO toDTO(Tecnico technician) {
            String displayingName = technician.getUsuario().getName();

            Set<Range<LocalDate>> invalidDates =
                    findTechnicalUserAbsences.findByTecnicoId(technician.getId())
                                             .stream()
                                             .map(absence -> new Range<>(toLocalDate(absence.getFechaInicio()),
                                                                         toLocalDate(absence.getFechaFin())))
                                             .collect(Collectors.toSet());

            return new TechnicianDatesDTO(displayingName, invalidDates);
        }

        private LocalDate toLocalDate(Date date) {
            return date != null ? date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate() : null;
        }
    }
```

I guess this is a deep Java working way problem that i dont understand and i m probably far from it...

Should work the same way as:

```
return findTechnician.findWithUser()
                          .stream()
                          .map(t->toDTO(t))
                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: instead of writing `this::toDTO` you should the `TechniciansModel::toDTO`. :: is used with the class name not by the object

Answer (score 1):

try as below:

```
return findTechnician.findWithUser()
       .stream()
       .map(TechniciansModel::toDTO)
       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

**::** is used with the class name not by the object.

Comment: I used many times this:: coding, and worked perfectly until now.

Btw, cant use TechniciansModel cause it would make me declare the method as static, so i wouldnt have access to the bean injected

Comment: any specific reason why you have made your class as private?

Comment: It's an inner class designed to be exclusively used by the one that contains it, it doesn't need to have more visibility than that, plus the resulting class isn't big enough to extract its inner